# Not understanding the issue with my solution to a palindrome problem

Tags: java, string, for-loop, integer, palindrome

I'm trying to solve a question where your code is supposed to determine if a given number is a palindrome or not, and I don't understand why it isn't working.

(You can skip this and just read the code if you want) The idea was that I create a string with the value of the integer, and create a for loop using the length of said string that uses % 10 to reverse the integer and store it in a separate string. I would then compare the 2 strings to determine if the number is a palindrome or not

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        int count = s.length();
        String palindrome = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            palindrome += x % 10;
        }
        System.out.print(palindrome);
        if(palindrome == s){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the code only returns false, and when I added a print statement to check what the reversed number (String palindrome) is, I got a different number.

For ex. I used 121 to test it and after the for loop the print statement outputted 111.

***I'm not really looking for a solution***, I just want to understand why it's behaving like this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        palindrome += x % 10;
    }
```

Since `x` does not change in that loop (or indeed anywhere in the code), each execution yields the same thing, the least significant digit of `x`.

Thus `palindrome` has some number of copies of the same digit, and will almost never equal `s`

You need to divide `x` by 10 each time around the loop.